# Play 2.0 Framework external Model in Template

Tags: playframework-2.0

Is it possible in Play 2.0, to make use of external model objects in a template?

I can reference model objects from another jar in a Controller class.  I don't know how to reference external model objects inside the Play 2.0 template files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem. 
First, add the class to your classpath, either by adding the jar to the lib dir or through the "managed dependencies" in the projects/Build.scala.
Make sure to have fully qualified name when declaring your model class in the template view file. 
Inside the template, you can reference any public method or member.

```
@(varName : fully.qualified.name.MyClass)
<h1>@varName.myMember</h1>
<h1>@varName.myMethod</h1>
```