# How to access models beyond the page scope in a template of Play! Framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

In Play! template I tried to access some models as I did in JSP with beans, the template recognize the model class but when I tried to access the model property, it complained error: "MissingPropertyException : No such property"

In my template:

**${fulllyQualifyName.myModel}**   (a model not passed from controller)

output on page: fulllyQualifyName.class

**${fulllyQualifyName.myModel.propertyA}**  (try to get the propertyA)

output on page: MissingPropertyException : No such property: propertyA for class: fulllyQualifyName.myModel Possible solutions: id,....

And I do have this propertyA set as property in myModel.

Should I include/import the model class first in the template? If so how could I do it? 
Thank you!

Comment: Not a static property. My questions is like this thread, but I am using Play 1.2.4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316827/play-2-0-framework-external-model-in-template/8693533#8693533

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access models in your view just passed them in controller render method i.e.

```
render(model1,model2...)
```

then you can use

```
${fullyQualifyName.model1.propertyA} 

${fullyQualifyName.model2.propertyB}
```

Also see: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/templates

Comment: Thanks for response, but in this case I use renderJSON(something), so I don't know how to pass another instance. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: why you are passing json and using play templates?

Comment: The javascript in the template make use of the json output, while I need to display other information from a model too. Thanks

Comment: I am not 100% positive but I think you have to have two different controllers one that will renderJson() and other one other one for the template. I guess the one that utilizes JSON is Ajax call.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing now.  Still I need to display some other info then the json document.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can access any packages in the view files. Just try:

```
${models.ModelClassName.find('queryStr').fetch()}
```

By this method, one can use all of the find() methods provided by the Model superclass, as described in http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/jpa#finding

For an example, if I want to retrieve a list of User without calling the controller render method:

```
#{list items:models.User.findAll(), as:'user'}
    user name: ${user.name}
#{/list}
```

To retrieve a specific user by id:

```
${models.User.findById(userId)}
```

...or by its own property:

```
${models.User.find('byEmail', 'john@gmail.com').first()}
```

If you wish to use the retrieved model in more than one places, you can try something like this:

```
%{
  users = models.User.findAll();
}%

<span>there are ${users.size()} user(s) </span>
<ul>
  #{list items:users, as:'user'}
    <li>${user.name}</li>
  #{/list}
</ul>
...
```

I hope this helped.