# Reference model in template beyond request / page scope, in Play! 1.2.4

Tags: playframework-1.x

I came across at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316827/play-2-0-framework-external-model-in-template/8693533#8693533), does anybody know how to do this in Play! 1.2.4?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The same effect is not quite possible, I think. You can of course reference classes in your Models package by using fully qualified names (`models.YourModel`) to access enumerations, for example.

Anything you add in the `renderArgs` scope in your controller will be available in the template, plus there are some implicit objects that are always in use (see [Play framework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates#implicits) for full listing). For example the `play.Play` object contains all kinds of useful stuff.

With `@Before` and `@With` annotations you can set up a controller used by multiple other controllers to have objects "globally" available - see [Interceptions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#interceptions).

Answer (score 0):

Even better, create a super controller extending Controller. Afterwards, let all your controllers extends your SuperController.

```
class SuperController extends Controller {

    @Before
    public static function before() {
        // Set global variables using renderArgs
    }
}

class MyController extends SuperController {

     public function myMethod() {
         // Do whatever your method does.
     }
}
```

Check out the documentation : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#result